# atomic_thread_fence requirement in a sequence lock

Tags: c++, thread-safety, atomic, lock-free, memory-barriers

I'm writing a simple [sequence lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seqlock)  and after reading through the c++ docs on atomics and atomic_thread_fence, it feels like I should need a fence.  However, Ive written it without a fence and I have a fairly rigorous test that seems to pass without it.

The basic sequence lock concept goes like this.  You have a single writer that constantly updates some piece of shared memory in place.  It associates an incrementing sequence number with the data.  Before it starts writing it increments once, when its done writing it increments again.

On the reader end, before it starts looking at the data it waits for the sequence number to turn even ( if its odd that means we are mid-write ).  It then keeps track of the sequence number it sees at the start, copies out the data locally, then checks the sequence number again when its done.  If they match, then the data is clean and usable.  If they dont match, then we are susceptible to a partial-read and we try again.

The sequencer number is stored in an std::atomic.  The writer updates it with a store( std::memory_order_release ) at the beginning and end of the block.
The reader reads the sequence number with a load( std::memory_order_acquire ) at the beginning and end of the read.

The data in question to be copied form writer -> reader is completely independent of the atomic seqno, which is why I was under the impression I may need a fence here to synchronize the dependency-less data... but it seems to work no matter what I throw at it.
I am running on a multi-socket / multi-core Intel Xeon machine, maybe it works specifically on this CPU?

Code snippets:

```
void SequenceLock::writeLock()
{
    m_seqno.store( m_seqno.load( std::memory_order_relaxed ) + 1, std::memory_order_release );
}

void SequenceLock::writeUnlock()
{
    m_seqno.store( m_seqno.load( std::memory_order_relaxed ) + 1, std::memory_order_release );
}

uint64_t SequenceLock::enterRead() const
{
    uint64_t seqno;
    while( ( seqno = m_seqno.load( std::memory_order_acquire ) ) & 1 ) {} //no yield, expect readers to be pinned
    return seqno;
}

bool SequenceLock::validateRead( uint64_t prevSeqno ) const
{
    return m_seqno.load( std::memory_order_acquire ) == prevSeqno;
}


//sample writer
lock.writeLock()
//update some shared data
lock.writeUnlock()

//sample reader
uint64_t seqno;
do {
    seqno = lock.enterRead()
    //copy shared data locally
} while( !lock.validateRead( seqno ) )
```

EDIT: Stranger still, I changed all the memory accessed above to memory_order_relaxed and it *still* seemed to work... odd

Comment: I've not looked through your code, but its worth nothing that the `x64` ISA is ridicullously strong by default. The CPU can and will cover up a lot of gaps in multithreading code. It doesn't mean your code is right, it just means it'll likely work. See [this good article](https://preshing.com/20120930/weak-vs-strong-memory-models/) from more info

Comment: Yes, I found C++'s memory model / rules somewhat inconvenient for implementing a SeqLock.  e.g. you want to let the compiler use efficient large stores to copy the data, without forcing it into small chunks that can be lock-free with `std::atomic<T>`.  That will technically create data-race UB, but is still safe on any real implementation.  See [Implementing 64 bit atomic counter with 32 bit atomics](//stackoverflow.com/q/54611003) for my attempt.  And yes, I found I needed fences.

Comment: @MikeVine: note that the C++ memory model is still weak.  So when testing on x86, in many cases the only danger is compile-time reordering, when StoreLoad reordering / the store buffer isn't a problem.  Like here where one thread is only storing and the other is only reading.  (x86-TSO is sequential consistency + a store buffer with store-forwarding.)

Comment: @PeterCordes If you know your CPU, you can use volatile operations that you know are atomic or safe in presence of a data race (all CPU are safe in presence of a data race). In C/C++ `volatile` gives you exactly the semantics of the CPU. You can now use compiler fences to "attach" volatile operation so that they are done in order with non volatile operation, something that wasn't portably available before: volatiles operations like stdio were done in order WRT to each others but WRT to non volatile operations.

Comment: `memory_order_release` on a lock operation is patently incorrect. Of course just because some ordering is allowed by high level semantic doesn't mean it will occur, or that the compiler is only capable of performing it in a single case!

Comment: @curiousguy: In C++, you can't do struct assignment from a `volatile struct foo` to a `struct foo tmp`.  So you can't just ask your compiler to efficiently copy an arbitrary type for you, unfortunately, if it's volatile.  In C you can.

Comment: @curiousguy: A SeqLock only works on its own for a single writer, so release order is correct.  It's not a real "lock", it's a way for a writer to publish a value to multiple lock-free readers.  (And when the value isn't in the middle of being modified, the readers are wait-free).  If you have multiple writers, they need to use a mutex or something to get exclusive write access to the SeqLock.

Comment: @PeterCordes I understand that only one writer is allowed here.

Comment: The silly part of this lock is forcing the writer to re-read the atomic sequence number, instead of just storing `seq+1` and `seq+2` from one read.  ("lock" should return the sequence number to be passed to "unlock".)

Comment: @curiousguy: oh, I see what you're saying.  Yes, you need an `atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release)` in the `lock` function, after storing `seq+1`.  Otherwise the release-store can reorder with the non-atomic stores in the "critical section".  My implementation in [Implementing 64 bit atomic counter with 32 bit atomics](//stackoverflow.com/q/54611003) does that.